# Two different axis labels in one pgfplots graph

Tags: pgfplots

Is there any way in pgfplots describe the positive part of the x-axis labels above the axis and the negative part of the x-axis label below the axis? The point is that if the graph of the function is partly above and partly below the axis, thus I am not able to do that to me at least one part of labels on the axis not overwrite graph of function.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\def\AddLabel(#1,#2)#3{\node \[align = center\] at (axis cs: #1,#2) {#3};}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\function{rad(atan((1.73205*\x)/(1-(\x)^2)))}
\def\functionlabel{\arctan\frac{\sqrt{3}\cdot x}{1-x^2}}

\begin{axis}\[
        xmin=-10,
        xmax=10, 
        domain=-9.5:9.5,
        ymin=-3,
        ymax=3,
        y domain=-3:3,
        width=\textwidth,
    height=0.4\textwidth,
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle, 
        axis equal=true,
        xlabel=$x$, 
        ylabel=$y$,          
        samples=600,
        clip=true,
        xticklabel style={anchor=north,yshift=5mm},
        yticklabel style={anchor=west,xshift=0.5mm},
\] 


\addplot\[line width=1.5pt,domain=-9.5:-1.01,y domain=-3:3\]{\function};
\addplot\[line width=1.5pt,domain=-0.99:0.99, y domain=-3:3\]{\function};
\addplot\[line width=1.5pt,domain=1.01:9.5,y domain=-3:3\]{\function};
\AddLabel(4,-1.5){$f\!:\ y=\functionlabel$}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample graph]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use normal ticks for one half of the axis, and `extra x ticks` for the other half, and then set `every extra x tick/.style={xticklabel style={anchor=north}}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\function{rad(atan((1.73205*\x)/(1-(\x)^2)))}

\begin{axis}[
        xmin=-10,
        xmax=10, 
        domain=-9.5:9.5,
        ymin=-3,
        ymax=3,
        y domain=-3:3,
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle, 
        axis equal image,        
        samples=50,
        clip=true,
        xticklabel style={anchor=south},
        yticklabel style={anchor=west,xshift=0.5mm},
        xtick={5,10},
        extra x ticks={-10,-5},
        every extra x tick/.style={
            xticklabel style={anchor=north}        
        }
] 


\addplot[line width=1.5pt,domain=-9.5:-1.01,y domain=-3:3]{\function};
\addplot[line width=1.5pt,domain=-0.99:0.99, y domain=-3:3]{\function};
\addplot[line width=1.5pt,domain=1.01:9.5,y domain=-3:3]{\function};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the nice trick (at least for me) and inspiration for next work. It works as I need. Thanks again. Jaroslav