# Modifying some features in a scatter plot (Version 3)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Here is code that renders a scatter plot. There are only two typical modifications that I want. First, I want labels on the axes. In the axis environment, I have `align=center,`, `ylabel = Number of Unsold \\ Candy Bars,`, and `xlabel = Number of Days,`. Why are the labels not being printed?  Second, I want to make the dots representing the data to be a bit smaller so that the two tick marks can be visible.  (The tick marks at 10 on the x-axis and 120 on the y-axis seem to be obscured by the dots for the scatter plot.)

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[grid=none, align=center, title=\textbf{George's Unsold Candy Bars},
    ylabel = Number of Unsold \\ Candy Bars,
    xlabel = Number of Days,
    xmin=0,xmax=11,ymin=0,ymax=130,
    xtick={10},ytick={120},
    yticklabel style={anchor=east},
    axis on top,axis lines=middle,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south east}
    ]

\addplot[only marks] coordinates{(0,120) (1,108) (2,96) (3,84) (4,72) (5,60) (6,48) (7,36) (8,24) (9,12) (10,0)};

\end{axis}

\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\node (origin) at ($(O)+(225:10pt)$) {$0$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `xlabel={abc}` is the right way, i.e. use braces.

Comment: @henry   See the code at "Modifying some features in a scatter plot (Version 2)."  Alenanno does not use braces and the labels are printed along the axes.

Comment: you have your `xlabel` and `ylabel` defined twice. Get rid of the second definition `xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,`

Comment: @Maarten Dhondt  Thanks.  To be consistent with other graphs in a file, I do want the `x` and `y` typeset in these exact locations with respect to the arrowheads.  How would I do that using a `\node` command or a `\coordinate` command?

Comment: You could probably get this done with an `extra x ticks` and `extra y ticks` hack or indeed with `\node`s. But I'm pretty sure an axis shouldn't represent two different units (`$x$` and `Number of Days`) at the same time.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232243/two-different-axis-labels-in-one-pgfplots-graph

Comment: @Maarten Dhondt   I looked at the post you suggested. I guess that you are suggesting that I label the x-axis as `x` using `extra x ticks={blah},` and `every extra x tick/.style={xticklabel style={anchor=north west}` and that I label the y-axis as `y`  using `extra y ticks={blah-blah},` and `every extra y tick/.style={xticklabel style={anchor=south west}`.  Do I replace `blah` with `x` and `blah-blah` with `y`?

Comment: @user74973 No, the `$x$` and `$y$` are labels, not ticks. I answered this question. Check that answer for the right syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The axis labels `ylabel = Number of Unsold \\ Candy Bars` and `xlabel = Number of Days` aren't displayed because you overwrite them with `ylabel = $y$` and `xlabel = $x$`. You can only have one label per axis.

To get a second label one could use `extra ticks`:

```
extra x ticks       = {5.5},
extra x tick style  = {xtick style={draw=none},xticklabel style={yshift=-5mm}},
extra x tick labels = {Number of Days},
extra y ticks       = {65},
extra y tick style  = {ytick style={draw=none},yticklabel style={xshift=-5mm,rotate=90}},
extra y tick labels = {Number of Unsold \\ Candy Bars}
```

or `\node`s:

```
\node at (3.5,-.75) {Number of Days};
\node[rotate=90,align=center] at (-1.25,3) {Number of Unsold \\ Candy Bars};
```

The size of the plot marks is set with `mark size` as a `\addplot` option.

Code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[   grid                = none, 
                            title               = \textbf{George's Unsold Candy Bars},
                            align               = center,
                            xmin                = 0,
                            xmax                = 11,
                            ymin                = 0,
                            ymax                = 130,
                            xtick               = {10},
                            ytick               = {120},
                            axis lines          = middle,
                            xlabel              = $x$,
                            ylabel              = $y$,
                            xlabel style        = {at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
                            ylabel style        = {at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south east},
                            extra x ticks       = {5.5},
                            extra x tick style  = {xtick style={draw=none},xticklabel style={yshift=-5mm}},
                            extra x tick labels = {Number of Days},
                            extra y ticks       = {65},
                            extra y tick style  = {ytick style={draw=none},yticklabel style={xshift=-5mm,rotate=90}},
                            extra y tick labels = {Number of Unsold \\ Candy Bars}
                        ]

            \addplot[mark size=0.5,only marks] coordinates{(0,120) (1,108) (2,96) (3,84) (4,72) (5,60) (6,48) (7,36) (8,24) (9,12) (10,0)};
        \end{axis}

        \node at (225:10pt) {$0$};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \vspace*{2cm}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[   grid         = none, 
                            title        = \textbf{George's Unsold Candy Bars},
                            align        = center,
                            xmin         = 0,
                            xmax         = 11,
                            ymin         = 0,
                            ymax         = 130,
                            xtick        = {10},
                            ytick        = {120},
                            axis lines   = middle,
                            xlabel       = $x$,
                            ylabel       = $y$,
                            xlabel style = {at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
                            ylabel style = {at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south east}
                        ]

            \addplot[mark size=0.5,only marks] coordinates{(0,120) (1,108) (2,96) (3,84) (4,72) (5,60) (6,48) (7,36) (8,24) (9,12) (10,0)};
        \end{axis}

        \node at (225:10pt) {$0$};
        \node at (3.5,-.75) {Number of Days};
        \node[rotate=90,align=center] at (-1.25,3) {Number of Unsold \\ Candy Bars};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

`extra ticks`:

[image]

`\node`:

[image]

Comment: Very nice!  If I have several graphs in a file with labels for the
axes besides `x` and `y`, I want there to be consistency with them.  In particular, 
I want the distances between labels and the axes to be consistent.  (Maybe I should say
"consistent algorithm" to determine such distances.  The distances would be different
for a graph in which there were no numbers along the y-axis than for a graph with 5-digit
numbers along the y-axis.)  I wouldn't
get that with your code.  So, I would like to have `xlabel = {Number of Days}` and
`ylabel = {Number of Unsold \\ Candy Bars}`.

Comment: In my post, I position the `x` and `y`
with `xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},`
and with `ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}`.
I do not know what the manual is saying about the `*` version of the
`ticklabel` version in `at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}`.  How would I
position the `x` and `y` in the same locations using a node command?